# How can we assign different lighting page layout for different record types from the community builder

Tags: page-layout, lightning-community

In service cloud we created different lightning page layouts for different record types and assigned accordingly. For reference see in the attachment.[image: lightning page layout assignment]

I have same requirements for the community. How can we assign different lighting page layout for different record types from the community builder?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Page Variation in Community. [Audience Targeting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5) feature in Community lets you to assign a Community Page based on certain conditions.

This feature lets you define criteria based on the following attributes:

- Profile
- Location
- Domain
- User Object
- **Record Type**
- Permission